# preg_match_all between two html phrases

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to substract the link from 
`<a class="link" href="http://www.x.ro/index.php?page=profile&amp;aid=560030" title="Profilul lui`

i tried

```
<?php
$output2='<a class="link" href="http://www.x.ro/index.php?page=profile&amp;aid=560030" title="Profilul lui';
preg_match_all('#<a\sclass="link"\shref="(.*?)"\stitle="Profilul#i', $output2, $match);
print_r ($match);
?>
```

nothing shown...
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>

SOLVED ... It seems like print_r just didn`t show anything, i don`t know why. var_dump worked like a charm

Comment: Try `var_dump()` instead (and **always** use it for debugging instead of `echo` or `print_r`)

Comment: it worked. Thank you. I don`t know why print_r didn`t work...

Comment: Since this is now solved, could someone write an answer and mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain that `print_r` is not working because of the unbalanced double quotes and the opening angled bracket in the regex. I changed the input string a bit to:

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.x.ro/index.php?page=profile&amp;aid=560030" title="Profilul lui"
```

[I added the last quote]

And your regex to:

```
#<a\sclass="link"\shref="(.*?)"\stitle="Profilul lui#i
```

And notice [this](http://viper-7.com/Ty5cHX) against [this](http://viper-7.com/JOO1Lg).

Or, without the opening angled bracket:

```
#a\sclass="link"\shref="(.*?)"\stitle="Profilul lui#i
```

[See the change](http://viper-7.com/zO8Xys)

Even `var_dump`'s output is affected in viper-7... but you can at least see the matches.

Note that if you do `print_r($match[1]);` you get a more decent print :)